# Sql decimal values not geting stored in temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating empty temporary table based on another table in my db and adding an extra column (`PRICE`) which i am trying to populate from query,

```
SELECT TOP 0 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber, 
 ID, 
 NULL AS PRICE 
 INTO #TMP_TABLE 
 FROM SQL_TABLE
```

when i fill this table as `INSERT INTO #TMP_TABLE ...` the value i am getting in `PRICE` column is either 0 or 1, but when i execute query seperately, i am getting decimal values (like`0.0634`).

how can i store decimal values in temp table above ? or is there any other way to create empty temp table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE` and define **explicitly columns types**:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_TABLE(RowNumber INT, ID <you_type>, Price <your_type>)
```

Default for `NULL` is `INT`, check:

```
SELECT x = NULL INTO #x;
EXEC tempdb..sp_columns '#x';
```

So your fraction are converted implicitly to `INT`

One good rule for future **EXPLICIT IS ALWAYS BETTER THAN IMPLICIT**

Comment: My problem was not explicitly defining the precision and scale of the decimal in the CREATE TABLE call.  The default is (18,0), which gives functionally an int. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

you either create the table with a create table statement:

```
create table #TMP_TABLE 
( RowNumber int 
, ID <whatever datatype>
, PRICE numeric(10,2)
);
```

or if you insist on select into declare the datatype :

```
SELECT TOP 0 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber, 
  ID, 
  cast(NULL as numeric(10,2)) AS PRICE 
INTO #TMP_TABLE 
FROM SQL_TABLE
```